# I cannot add cloud_firestore and firebase_auth together in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I can't use the latest versions as I will get an error as `firestore` depends on some platform handler, and after some research, these are the compatible versions.

If I add them together, I get the error of duplicate class.

I searched half of these classes from `Navigate>Class` (include packages is tick), no classes found.

I am using `google sign in` and saving credentials and some data concerning the users google id.

I want to use 2 flutter plugins:

```
firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
cloud_firestore:  ^0.14.0+2
```

Also included:

```
firebase_core: ^0.5.0
permission_handler: ^5.1.0+2
```

Any help is appreciated :)

```java
Launching lib\main.dart on {MOBILE NAME} in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractProtobufList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.BooleanArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteBufferWriter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteOutput found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ArraysByteArrayCopier found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$BoundedByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteArrayCopier found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteIterator found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$CodedBuilder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LeafByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LiteralByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$Output found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$SystemByteArrayCopier found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$AbstractBufferedEncoder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$ArrayEncoder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$ByteOutputEncoder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutOfSpaceException found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.DoubleArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExperimentalApi found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryFactory found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite$ObjectIntPair found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet$FieldDescriptorLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FloatArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$DefaultInstanceBasedParser found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableBuilder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage$ExtensionWriter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessageOrBuilder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtensionDescriptor found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$GeneratedExtension found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$MethodToInvoke found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$SerializedForm found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.IntArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$BooleanList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$DoubleList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$EnumLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$EnumLiteMap found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$FloatList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$IntList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter$Converter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$LongList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$Converter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$EntryAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$IteratorAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$SetAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ProtobufList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
```

**keeps on for a few more classes**

```java
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$LazyEntry found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$LazyIterator found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyFieldLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList$ByteArrayListView found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList$ByteStringListView found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LongArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite$Metadata found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapFieldLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteOrBuilder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteToString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MutabilityOracle found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MutabilityOracle$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.NioByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.NioByteString$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Parser found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ProtobufArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ProtocolStringList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.RopeByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.RopeByteString$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.RopeByteString$Balancer found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.RopeByteString$PieceIterator found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.RopeByteString$RopeInputStream found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$EmptySet found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$EmptySet$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$EmptySet$2 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$Entry found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$EntryIterator found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$EntrySet found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TextFormatEscaper found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TextFormatEscaper$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TextFormatEscaper$2 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TextFormatEscaper$ByteSequence found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UninitializedMessageException found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSetLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList$2 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8$Processor found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8$SafeProcessor found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation$2 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation$3 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 55s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the stack trace, you are getting a dependency resolution error message:

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 55s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolution_errors):

> When you add multiple dependencies to your app project, those direct and transitive dependencies might conflict with one another. The Android Gradle Plugin tries to resolve these conflicts gracefully, but some conflicts may lead to compile time or runtime errors.

If you follow the documentation for [duplicate class errors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes), it provides a detailed explanation on how to resolve this error.